# How to install hardware drivers for my laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, hardware, laptop, hp

Everytime I change the OS I usually format my laptop. It is an HP tx-2 Touchsmart. It has a touchscreen and additional hardware that isn't working (i.e. volume control buttons and the network discovery) If I was on windows I would just download the hardware drivers from the HP website. How do I go about installing the software for the built-in hardware of my laptop?

I am new to the community and I really want to get this computer working like it used to, to get the full Ubuntu experience. Please direct me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your hardware as open drivers for Ubuntu, they will be install with Ubuntu. If there is driver from HP, you can find them into your Setting->Additional drivers.

This is Jockey, and it will let you know which drivers are available for your hardware. Just select which one you want and click Install.